# Django - getting entries from a foreign key relationship for csv output

Tags: python, django, csv

I am exporting some data in a Django view to csv, simplified code example below. I want to get all the games from the Game model and for each game, get the scores (one to many relationship).  I am getting the error `tuple object has no attribute score_set` so the below code which I have tried doesn't appear to be the correct way to do this. I have no problem with getting the Game objects exported alone. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="stuff.csv"'

writer = csv.writer(response)

writer.writerow(['Name',
                 'Details',
                 'More details'])

games = Game.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('name',
                                                          'details',
                                                          'more_details')


for game in games:
    scores = game.score_set.all().values_list('score',
                                              'date_played')
    writer.writerow(game)

    for score in scores:    
        writer.writerow(score)

return response
```

Comment: If you intend to deliver nested data with CSV - that is a bad idea, think of CSV as a representation of a single table - either you export 2 CSV files (one containing the games, the other the scores and link them with FK to PK), or export the data with JSON or XML.

Comment: Yes absolutely, but the requirement is only for the user to download their data so that they can view it offline, not for onward consumption :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's [`Queryset.values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) method returns a Queryset of tuples. Thus, your loop that looks like `for game in games:` sets the name `game` to a tuple representing each element of the Queryset.

Without more information, namely the contents of a `Game` model, it's hard to say exactly how to extract the data you're looking for. From your code, it looks like your goal would be an output that looks something like:

```
Name | Details | More Details |
some_name | some_detail | some_more_detail
10 | October 25
11 | November 1
9 | November 7
0 | November 28
some_name2 | some_detail2 | some_more_detail2
...
```

Imagining the numbers are the scores of a game, so I'll go with that in hopes of getting you started.

First, go ahead and just get a Queryset of `Game`s instead of tuples. Replace:

```
games = Game.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('name',
                                                      'details',
                                                      'more_details')
```

With:

```
games = Game.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Now in your loop, assuming `Score`s have a `ForeignKey` resulting in a reverse-lookup field named `score_set` in `Game`, use:

```
 for game in games:
     # I'm just going to construct a single tuple for the game info:
     game_attrs = (game.name, game.details, game.more_details)

     score_attrs_list = game.score_set.values_list('score', 'date_played')  # (No need for .all() here, .values_list() will handle the query)
     writer.writerow(game_attrs)
     for score_attrs in score_attrs_list:
           writer.writerow(score_attrs)
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas, that's what I needed, will need to sort out formatting but it was getting the data that was the main issue